# Pandas - Add dummy rows with some values in between of Pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas

I'm newbie to Pandas Python.

I've a Pandas.Series value:

```
month   id
01_Jan  1                3
02_Feb  1                2
        2                4
03_Mar  1                2
        3                5
dtype: int64
```

*month and id are indexes and last column is series in pandas.*

Here, month has 4 values such as "01_Jan", "02_Feb", "03_Mar".
      id Count such as 1,2,3
      series has some counts 3,2,4,2,5.

I need to reformat the above Series type in such a way that if **id** doesn't has **month** then it should add the appropriate month with count value **0**. Below *pandas.Series* explains how should it looks like:

```
month   id
01_Jan  1                3
01_Jan  2                0
01_Jan  3                0
02_Feb  1                2
02_Feb  2                4
02_Feb  3                0
03_Mar  1                2
03_Mar  2                0
03_Mar  3                5
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels, names=s.index.names)
print (s.reindex(mux, fill_value=0))
month   id
01_Jan  1     3
        2     0
        3     0
02_Feb  1     2
        2     4
        3     0
03_Mar  1     2
        2     0
        3     5
dtype: int64
```

Another solution with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) + [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), but it can be slowier in large `DataFrame`:

```
print (s.unstack(fill_value=0).stack())
month   id
01_Jan  1     3
        2     0
        3     0
02_Feb  1     2
        2     4
        3     0
03_Mar  1     2
        2     0
        3     5
dtype: int64
```